# INNER JOIN PHP - NO MUESTRA DATOS EN MI TABLAS

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente problemática.
Tengo dos tablas en una base de datos, la primera es "regisro_expedientes" que cuenta con la siguiente información:
Matricula, Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, Procedencia, Carrera, Departamento, Edad, Telefono, HServicio

La segunda tabla es "checador_registro" y cuenta con la siguiente información: MatriculaCH, Motivo, Tiempo, Fecha, Horario

Ambas las quiero unir en una sola.

--- Este es mi codigo ---

```
<?php

$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sintesis');
 
// Extraer los datos de el usuario que se tiene dentro de la variable de la sesion
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM registro_expedientes WHERE Matricula ";
$ejecuta = $conexion->query($consulta);
$extraer = $ejecuta ->fetch_assoc();
// Consulta con INNER JOIN - Union de tablas. 
$unir = "SELECT
re.Matricula, re.Nombre, re.ApellidoPaterno, re.ApellidoMaterno,
cr.Matricula, cr.Motivo, cr.Tiempo, cr.Fecha, cr.Horario
FROM registro_expedientes re
JOIN checador_registro cr
ON re.Matricula = ch.Matricula"; 
// Para Ejecutar la consulta.
$verificar = $conexion->query($unir);
// Verificar las lineas que tenemos
$separar = $verificar->fetch_array();

?>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Matricula</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                                <th>Apellido Materno</th> 
                                <th>Procedencia</th> 
                                <th>Motivo</th> 
                                <th>Fecha</th>                             
                                <th>Entrada</th>
                                <th>Salida</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['Matricula']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['Nombre']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['ApellidoPaterno']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['ApellidoMaterno']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['Procedencia']?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['Motivo']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['Tiempo']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['Fecha']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $extraer['Harario']?></td>
                            </tr>
            
                        </tbody>        
                       </table>
```

Comment: Pero bro, haz un JOIN !!

Comment: Primero, tu consulta esta mal hecha `$consulta = "SELECT * FROM registro_expedientes WHERE Matricula";`... EL WHERE NO TIENE QUE BUSCAR

Comment: @Excorpion Entonces el INNER JOIN que esta arriba, ese no es o no sirve para la unión de las tablas.

Comment: @Excorpion Si.
Eh puesto el siguiente comando SQL en mi código, ya no me arroba errores, pero no me muestra datos.
`
SELECT * FROM registro_expedientes INNER JOIN checador_registro ON registro_expedientes.Matricula = checador_registro.MatriculaCH;
`

Comment: @Excorpion Ya me muestra valores de la primer tabla, de la segunda aun no me muestra nada. Cambie el mostrar, por extraer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para unir ambas tablas, solo necesitas 1 consulta.

```
SELECT re.Matricula, re.Nombre, re.ApellidoPaterno, re.ApellidoMaterno,
cr.MatriculaCH, cr.Motivo, cr.Tiempo, cr.Fecha, cr.Horario 
FROM registro_expedientes re 
JOIN checador_registro cr ON re.Matricula = cr.MatriculaCH
```

**Esta consulta en mysql, te traería todos los datos de ambas tablas, SI ES QUE sus Matriculas coinciden.**

Comment: Si me sirvió, Pero solo me muestra de la primer tabla, de registro, mas no de checador, ya verifique la matriculas y son iguales.

Comment: Ahora si, prueba

Comment: ya probe, me sale el mismo error, que las claves definidas como:  Motivo, Fecha, Entrada y Salida, no están definidas. 

Ya las verifique, en mi base de datos, como en mi codigo, las tengo definidas de la misma forma

Comment: Espera, cual entra y salida, no hay eso en la consulta

Comment: Muchas Gracias bro, eh podido solucionar el codigo.

Comment: Deberías explicar que hace (JOIN y ON) y citar la documentación oficial sobre su sitio.

Comment: No quiero :P este tema fue tratado por chat

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso Hola compañero programador, el otro compañero me ha explicado por medio de disscord, como funciona el JOIN Y ON. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: @Excorpion seria bueno que lo agregaras del chat recuerda que las respuestas son para la comunidad...